# TCPDF: HTML table and margins

Tags: php

I am creating an HTML table and I have problem with margins as you can see in the following image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5K9t.jpg How can I remove those left and top margins?

Answer (score 4):

I use a empty table to set margin

```
    <your top table>
    <table border="0">
    <tr style="line-height: 40%;" > 
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <your second table>
```

Enjoy it

Comment: Clear Shot, Buddy. :)

Answer (score -1):

I used TCPDF before and tried hard to know it

you can see in /config/ folder /tcpdf_config.php/ file

you should looking up for

```
/**
 * header margin
 */
define ('PDF_MARGIN_HEADER', 5);

/**
 * footer margin
 */
define ('PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER', 10);

/**
 * top margin
 */
define ('PDF_MARGIN_TOP', 27);

/**
 * bottom margin
 */
define ('PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM', 25);

/**
 * left margin
 */
define ('PDF_MARGIN_LEFT', 15);

/**
 * right margin
 */
define ('PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT', 15);
```

Answer (score -1):

**For the interested, just do as follows and it will work like a charm:**

```
$pdf->SetMargins(0, 0, 0);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(0);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(0);
```